# How to hide export table functions names in PE?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, g++, portable-executable

For ELF in Linux works `strip <mybinary>` well, but idk how to hide all functions names in PE file.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling "strip PE files" is yielding a bunch of results, including tools.

Comment: You mean relocation table? I don't think it will work for windows DLLs, but you could try to do it for .exe, smoething like http://www.heaventools.com/remove_relocations.htm

Comment: But PE explorer works only with 32bit PE images.

Answer (score 2):

"By using the optional NONAME keyword, you can export by ordinal only..." and thus remove the name of the function exported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

But if you remove an entry of the export table altogether, you won't be able to import it from another library.

Items (functions, variables) must be exported either by name or by ordinal.